# JavaScript/CSS Play Spritesheet once then change to gif?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this game going on. I need to have it, when idle, play [this gif](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragon.gif) and when a `function()` is called, I need it to loop through [this spritesheet](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragonFire.png) **ONCE** and then revert back to the [gif](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragon.gif). Here's my code, and the JavaScript I have **NO IDEA** how to do, but I tried anyway.

### CSS

```
.dragon  {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragonFire.png') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}
@keyframes play  {
  100% {background-position: -1200px;}
}
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
  var weapon = [];
  var weapons = ['Claymore', 'Dagger', 'Magic Staff', 'Sword', 'Bow', 'Crossbow'];
  var armors = ['Helmet', 'Hood', 'Chestplate', 'Tunic', 'Robe', 'Legplates', 'Leggings', 'Undergarments', 'Boots', 'Armored Boots'];
  var materials = ['Leather', 'Iron', 'Steel', 'Mythril', 'Dragonbone'];
  var battleMusic = function()  {
    if(mute.checked == false)  { 
      document.getElementsByTagName("AUDIO")[0].play();
    }
    if(mute.checked === true)  {

    }
  }
  var dragonHit = function()  {
    var damage = dragonad / dp * 100;
    hp = hp - damage;
    Math.round(hp);
    alert("You were hit by the dragon! You currently have " + hp + " health!");
  }
  var hitDragon = function()  {
    var damage = ad / dragondp * 100;
    dragonhp = dragonhp - damage;
    Math.round(dragonhp);
    alert("You hit the dragon! The dragon now has " + dragonhp + " health!");
    if(weapon.hasOwnProperty("Magic Staff"))  {
      img.class = "dragon";
      hitDragon();
    }
  }
```

### HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <audio>
      <source src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/sound/Pokemon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser doesn't support the sound file for playback. The Dragon Battle will be silent!
    </audio>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="container">
          <input type="checkbox" value="mute" id="mute">Mute</input>
          <h2 class="header">Dragon Slayer - REBORN!</h2>
          <p class="intro">You are a dragon-slayer veteran! You are retired, relaxed, and comfortable in your home, with no-one to boss you around... then you hear the town sirens.</p>
          <a id="button" href="javascript:fight()"><br>BEGIN!</a>
          <img id="scenario" class=""  src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png">
          <div class="battles">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## WHAT'S SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN

The `img` starts with a blank class. By default, before the dragon fight, it will stay as the scenario. Once the `dragonFight()` function (included in the jcodepen with the full game) is called, it'll change the src of the image to the `dragon.gif`. If the player (array) has the weapon (property) of a Magic Staff, it shall play the `dragonFire.png` animation **ONCE** when they call the `ATTACK` function, then revert back to `dragon.gif`.

## CodePen w/ Full Game

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FelixTheSpy/pen/gbWZzZ)

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back, we had different animations in a big png image. What I ended up doing was working with classes. Set the element to .walk, wait for x seconds until the walk was completed and then set it back to .idle. In the css the .walk class would just be a backround image with the background position animated with steps and transitions. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Could you post an answer with an example? @JonasGrumann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:
http://jsfiddle.net/gkj1ef8d/

I used keyframe animations applied on a specific class to animate the spritesheet which is set as background-image. With this approach you can have as many animations as you want. I would suggest you put them all into a big png spritesheet that contains all the animations you need and then adjust the horizontal and vertical position of the image. That way, you'll only have one image to preload, resulting in faster load time and simpler code.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var dragon = document.querySelectorAll(".dragon")[0];

button.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragon.className+=" run";
    
    window.st = window.setTimeout(function(p) {
         dragon.className = dragon.className.replace(" run", "");
    }, 1000)
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes run {
    from {
        background-position: top left;
    }
    to {
        background-position: top right;
    }
}

.dragon {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
}

img {
   position: absolute;
    top: -9999999px
}
.dragon.run {
    background: url("http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragonFire.png") top left no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: run 1s steps(9) infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragonFire.png" alt=""><!-- The image is in the html to force it to preload, a better approach would be to preload it with JS, but this is out of the scope of the question -->
<div class="dragon"></div>

<button>Run</button>
```

Note that this example doesn't have all the vendor prefixes so it will only run on Chrome and maybe Safari.

Comment: I am unaware of jQuery coding knowledge, and my project runs off of JavaScript and gets confused and broken when I mix jQuery and JavaScript. I will give a 1 up for now, but if you can convert it to JavaScript, I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks! It will be VERY helpful if you can, @JonasGrumann

Comment: Sure, no problem. I updated my answer with a vanilla js solution.

Comment: One final request. How could I make it fit with my program? I tried working with it, but I can't figure it out. The jsFiddle will include the whole game, but you should focus on the `hitDragon()` function as well as the `variables`. I need it to change the background, or animated `dragon.gif`, to he animated spritesheet, looping once, then changing back to the gif. I would play through it once, just so you get the idea of how it works, which will probably make it easier to roubleshoot/understand. http://jsfiddle.net/TheGamingHideout/4joahpfx/   After this, I'll accept the answer @JonasGrumann

Comment: Just put the part after e.preventDefault() to }, 1000) inside your dragon hit function and paste/write the corresponding css